# How do i query the parts' volume information with abaqus python script in abaqus/cae and abaqus/viewer mode?

Tags: python, abaqus

in abaqus/cae mode ,i use getMassProperties() function to query the volume,but in viewr mode(visualization module only),that not work..

Comment: Why not just use cae mode?  I'd assume certain functionality is restricted in view only mode for licensing reasons.

Comment: Sometimes,we get everything ready in hyperworks,and use generated .inp files for solution.so we only get .odb file to handle.

Comment: you can open the odb in cae. (actually I have never used the visualization module, always run cae)

Comment: what object are you using the getMassPropertes on? are you sure you are importing the correct modules at the beginning of your script.

Comment: like this mdb.models['Handling_Bushing_A25-SF-20160106165108'].rootAssembly.getMassProperties()

Comment: i open the odb in cae.it's remain the same..cae module still got nothing .so the getMassProperties() command not working too.

Comment: i haven't find a command in odb module yet.if the problem can't be solved,i will restore the volume data in cae module ,so i can retrive it latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part volume in CAE:

```
 from abaqus import *
 mask=mdb.models['Model'].parts['part'].cells.getMask()
 cellobj_sequence=mdb.models['Model'].parts['part'].cells.getSequenceFromMask(mask=mask)
 part_volume=mdb.models['Model'].parts[part'].getVolume(cells=cellobj_sequence)
```

Assembly volume in CAE:

```
    from abaqus import *
    prop=mdb.models['Model'].rootAssembly.getMassProperties()
```

(Now, the 'prop' variable is a dictionary object. prop[volume] should give your desired result.

Option #2: If you want to access volumes of only certain part instances, create a part instance object and call that in your getMassProperties()

```
m=mdb.models['Model'].rootAssembly
inst=m.instances['instance'] 
mask=inst.cells.getMask()
partinstance_obj1=inst.cells.getSequenceFromMask(mask=mask)
prop1=mdb.models['Model'].rootAssembly.getMassProperties(regions=(partinstance_obj1,)) #Regions here will accept only a sequence of part instance obj
```